# ¿Ayuda con los headers en Angular en ionic? Error en al Authorization

Tags: java, android, angular, ionic, cordova

Estoy haciendo una app con ionic 6 utilizando angular 10 al momento de loguearme me devuelve los datos del usuario junto con un token que se genera en el server el token lo almaceno en el localStorage, cuando hago una peticion http le mando en los header el token pero no me da el siguente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el bakend estoy utilizando java con sprinboot ya le agregue la configuración de los cors y esta así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago la petición en postman funciona perfectamente pero cuando lo implemento en angular no funciona y me manda el error. Segun para ver si se están enviando los headers en chrome me aparece así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi método en angular es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Método donde inicio sesión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y Por ultimo donde la mando a llamar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si estoy mal en el mi frontend o en mi backend no se como ver si los header llegan al servidor intente debuguendo pero no, de antemano les agradezco por su ayuda y gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el backend tienes que añadir a la request los headers necesarios para cumplir la CORS policy.

Sí usas express te dejo un tutorial para ello.
[cabeceras](https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b)

Comment: Mi error es que me falto agregar el Authorization en los headers de mi server, gracias me ayudo mucho tu respuesta.